# "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" in Platform.js?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

After having a project in which we use both Angular.dart and Polymer.dart along with angular_node_bind.dart, we have a simple paper_element, menu button, clicking on it multiple times in short duration triggers this error message in console of dartium. How to get rid of this error? Also, why does it get triggered?

Comment: Seems like an endless loop. Can you make a minimal running example available at GitHub and report and error in the Angular and the angular_node_bind repo (and crosslink them).

Comment: A far shot but could be related to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular-dart/f1_HlDUfy3A